# Idiomatic expression with 'spot'

Tags: idioms

I am going nuts with the sentence below. I am supposed to fill in the gap with an expression containing the word in bracket **SPOT**. Can someone help me complete this sentence?

> "I can't understand poetry. I am afraid it is a...............(spot) with me."

I am very confused whether I have to use an idiom like "to be in a tight spot" or a phrasal verb or other. I have tried some expressions but the preposition WITH after the gap makes me think I am far from right in my guesses.

Comment: Looks like "sore spot" will work for you. "It's a sore spot with me" is a common English idiom, at least in AmE.

Comment: Is there a text ot site you're working with? OR are you just expected to come up with ideas out og the blue?

Comment: Sore/blind/weak -- there are several possible terms.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest this:

> I can't understand poetry. I am afraid it is a **blind spot** with me.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/blind_spot) has

> **blind spot**
>   NOUN
>
> **2.1** An area in which a person lacks understanding or impartiality.
>   *Ed had a blind spot where these ethical issues were concerned*

The sentence means that the speaker doesn't "get" poetry.

Answer (score 0):

Spot on.
Meaning "accurate".  His assessment was spot on.

Not sure if you will count this one:  spotless
Meaning unblemished.  His record was spotless.

Hit the spot.
He was hungry and eating the well cooked meal hit the spot.

Comment: I'm not sure which of these you consider suitable for the given sentence but I don't think any of them actually fit.